# ansible playbook command line / Jenkins Ansible plugin / parameter NOT accepting space(s) / comma(s) for host values

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-2.x, failed-to-connect

Jenkins version: 2.7.4
Ansible/Playbook version: 2.1.1.0

Ansible playbook file:
[ vagrant@/tmp ] $ ls -l pb.yml

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant vagrant 189 Nov  2 05:39 pb.yml
```

[ vagrant@/tmp ] $ cat $_

```
---
#- hosts: "{{ host }}"
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False

#  vars:
#   - host: "all"

  tasks:
    - name: Hello
      shell: "echo hello"
      tags:
         - hello

    - name: Bye
      shell: "echo bye"
      tags:
         - bye
```

When I run the following command on ansible/host machine **at command line**, it's working if I'm passing only one or more host(s), with or without a space after **","** character between hosts values:

```
$ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook tasks/pb.yml -i "app-server1" -f 5 --private-key /tmp/ssh738232337886876255.key -u ubuntu
```

if I pass more than one hosts (cmd line), it still works (PS: even if I have **,** as a suffix or not for the list of inventory hosts):

```
$ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook tasks/pb.yml -i "app-server1,web-server2" -f 5 --private-key /tmp/ssh738232337886876255.key -u ubuntu
$ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook tasks/pb.yml -i "app-server1,web-server2," -f 5 --private-key /tmp/ssh738232337886876255.key -u ubuntu
```

But, with a space character passed in **-i** option's value, I'm seeing it works for a server entry where space is not there and fails for the same host with space suffixed/prefixed (at least as per what's displayed on the stdout console).

For example running "-m setup" (gather facts) with ansible command, NOTICE the space character in the output below before *proxy-server3 | UNREACHABLE!* line.

If I run -m setup (ansible command) -or- even if I run the same playbook(ansible-playbook command), I see similar error UNREACHABLE as shown below:

```
$ /usr/bin/ansible all -m setup -i "app-server1, proxy-server3," -f 5 --private-key /tmp/ssh738232337886876255.key -u ubuntu

 proxy-server3 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
app-server1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "10.124.12.101"
        ],
        ...more...json...stuff..here
        ...
```

Now, I'm *Invoking Ansible Playbook* in Jenkins's build step.
In Jenkins I have a parameterized job parameter named *hosts*, which I'm using **within** "*Invoke Ansible Playbook*" plugin's build step as an "**inline content**" radio button for its **inventory** section.

When I'm passing only "app-server1" and launching the job, Jenkins is successfully running the job and running the ansible-playbook .yml file as expected.

But, when I'm giving *hosts* variable with multiple comma separated values, it's erroring out.

If *hosts* parameter in Jenkins is set to more than one host i.e.: 
**app-server1,web-server2**
OR 
**app-server1,app-server1** (without any space next to "," character) 
OR 
**app-server1,web-server2,**  (PS: here , is suffixed to the value).

I'm getting the following error:

```
23:48:00 PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
23:48:00 
23:48:00 TASK [hello] ******************************************************
23:48:01 fatal: [app-server1,web-server2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
23:48:01 
23:48:01 PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
23:48:01 app-server1,web-server2 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
23:48:01 
23:48:01 FATAL: command execution failed
23:48:01 hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
23:48:01    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:227)
23:48:01    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:200)
23:48:01    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
23:48:01    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
23:48:01    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
23:48:01 ERROR: Ansible playbook execution failed
23:48:01 Finished: FAILURE
```

**OR** 
(when **,** is used as suffix in the value of *hosts* parameter)

---

```
23:48:01 fatal: [app-server1,web-server2,]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
23:48:01 
23:48:01 PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
23:48:01 app-server1,web-server2, : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
23:48:01 
23:48:01 FATAL: command execution failed
```

**OR**
If I give a space between two hosts values (irrespective of the suffixed , character at the end), I get a different error message.

Example: I passed the following value to parameter *hosts*:
**app-server1, web-server2**
or
**app-server1,web-server2, proxy-server3,**

Error example:

```
23:49:53 ERROR! /tmp/inventory5444675088910579622.ini:1: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: app-server1,
23:49:53 FATAL: command execution failed
23:49:53 hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
23:49:53    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:227)
23:49:53    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:200)
23:49:53    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
23:49:53    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
23:49:53    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
23:49:53 ERROR: Ansible playbook execution failed
```

**Questions:**

1. Why space is not getting removed automatically when I'm giving that in ansible command or ansible-playbook command for **-i** option's value? How can I get rid of the situation if hosts are passed with a space character around comma "**,**" character  within double quotes for **-i** option. I know I can use *sed* beforehand but **-i** option should ignore any spaces next to "**,**" character by default (whether  space(s) is/are prefixed/suffixed next to a comma character).
2. How come (**when I'm not giving any space** in the parameter's value) in my Jenkins job, it's erroring out when the value has "**,**", while it succeeds at command line?
3. Giving **-i "app-server1"** (at command line) is **not** working. But, it works when I give **-i "app-server1,"**  (see , at the end within quotes). 
   The same is totally behaving opposite in Jenkins using a parameter(string type) and using Invoke Ansible Playbook build step; there, if I give *hosts* parameter the value of "app-server1" it WORKS, but giving **"app-server1,"** (suffixing comma character) does **NOT**.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue and solution in Jenkins at least.

This seems like a **BUG or requires an Enhancement/feature request** in "**Ansible Plugin**" available in Jenkins (**or** may be I'm incorrect about what the term inline means) but when **INVENTORY** method is selected for "*inline content*" (a radio button) and if we use a variable ($hosts / etc) which contains comma separated and/or comma+space separated list of hostname/IPs etc, then Ansible is not working in running the playbook.

Opened a request against this plugin in Jenkins JIRA: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39611

The workaround of creating a inventory file, using "File" radio button / method within "Invoke Ansible Playbook" actually worked here but I was trying to use just a plain "${variable}" and my assumption was, the plugin  should treat that exactly like we pass **-i** option at command line.

So, an enhancement of having a **3rd radio button** would help a lot.

For ex:
Third radio button (**Comma separated list/variable**) and a user can just specify "${myHosts}" and be done with it (instead of creating a FILE and using File radio button **or** writing a proper INLINE inventory file when "inline content" method is used).

My assumption is it should work if I want to pass host(s) info as a comma separated / comma cum space separated list (as per --help documentation)  and mimicking the same within this plugin, see --help below for ansible / ansible-playbook **-i** option.

I guess for command line issue, commas/spaces have to solved using **sed** or **tr** similar commands.

**ansible** or **ansible-playbook** documentation says that **-i** option specifies the inventory (host info) to be used for Ansible to work on, we can define it as a relative/absolute path and it defaults to /etc/ansible/hosts OR **a comma separated host list**:

```
ansible --help || ansible-playbook --help

  -i INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path
                        (default=/etc/ansible/hosts) or comma separated host
                        list.
```

Anyways, my issue was around **comma separated host list** as it was NOT working in Jenkins within **Ansible Invoke Playbook** plugin's *build step* .

I was using $hosts or similar variable (as per the screenshot below) as "*inline content*" for **inventory** (radio button) method.

**What I did to resolve:**
I created a temporary (aka mktemp) file and filtering out the one liner host(s) info list containing space or comma into this temporary file and using this temporary file as "**File**" (**Radio button**) method for passing the inventory information (about the hosts) in "Invoke Ansible Playbook" build step.

Now, I'm not getting the above error messages in Jenkins. After the Ansible part is complete, I'm removing these temporary files (don't have to as they all sit in /tmp location, if you want them in your Jenkins workspace location then **mktemp -p .** can be used to create a temporary file in current working directory).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your bug report and analysis. I'm going to quickly look at it.